# Adding Links to Laravel Auth Navbar

Tags: laravel, authentication

I Installed Laravel and the authentication that comes standard. In the top right navbar, there is a dropdown menu that contains the logout link only. I am trying to add more links above the logout, but when I did so the new link completely replaces the logout one altogether. How can I add items without losing the logout link?

App.blade

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="/"><img src="images/FamiJam.svg"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/create">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}</a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: php artisan view:clear

Comment: which item did you try to add? About and Contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be super simple to do, I'm not sure what you're doing but to add additional links you can add an anchor tag to the dropdown div:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
```

For example:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        {{ __('Logout') }}
    </a>                             
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;"> 
        @csrf
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you... Silly mistake, I was adding the anchor tag in the wrong location.